# How to get all employee record bases of second highest salary

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I know how to get the second highest salary form database table using by

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) From Employee WHERE Salary < ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee);
```

But I want get all employee records whose salary is second largest salary into tables.

Comment: Can you be more clear? "But I want get all employee records whose salary is second largest salary into tables.". What do 'records' mean? Columns, or rows? And why are there so many employees with second largest salaries?

Comment: @ki want row and suppose maximum salary 5000 and second largest salary is 2000 and four employee has 2000 salary I want four employee record base of second largest salary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from employee where salary=(
SELECT MAX(Salary) From Employee WHERE Salary < ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it should work.

select * from Employee where Salary in (SELECT MAX(Salary) From Employee WHERE Salary < ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee));

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the employees whose salary equals the second highest salary you got:

```
set @second_top_salary=(
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee 
WHERE salary<( SELECT Max(salary) FROM employee)
);
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary=@second_top_salary;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d28a5/3)

Answer (score 0):

Using LIMIT:

```
SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 2) AS Emp ORDER BY Salary LIMIT 1
```